# spark-submit Error: No main class set in JAR; please specify one with --class

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to execute a spark application using spark-submit.

```
c:\temp>spark-submit --master yarn  ./SparkExamples.jar --class com.examples.WordCount
Error: No main class set in JAR; please specify one with --class
Run with --help for usage help or --verbose for debug output
```

The main class file is existing in the jar file.  I also checked there is a MANIFEST.MF file which holds the main class name.

Manifest-Version: 1.0

Main-Class: com.examples.WordCount

what am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try providing --class parameter first before ./SparkExamples.jar

```
spark-submit --master yarn  --class com.examples.WordCount ./SparkExamples.jar
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are including multiple jars as dependencies, make sure they are comma separated ***without spaces***. Took a while to figure out, but this was my issue, and the error messages was the opposite of helpful since the class name was clearly already present.

Here is an example below of what fixed it.

Example Code causing error:

```
spark-submit --jars jar1.jar, jar2.jar \
--class ClassName \
jar3.jar param1 param 2
```

Example code fixed:

```
spark-submit --jars jar1.jar,jar2.jar \
--class ClassName \
jar3.jar param1 param 2
```